# Maven (deploy-plugin) creating huge logs for Nexus

Tags: maven, logging, maven-2, nexus, maven-deploy-plugin

We are using Maven deploy plugin to deploy / upload the artifacts to our nexus repository. While doing the same, Maven is creating huge log files where it's just recording the nexus upload status like below:

```
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] Uploaded: http://[repo-location] (4 KB at 7.5 KB/sec)
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] Uploading: http://[repo-location]\server-6.03-b07-prd.war
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 2/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 4/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 6/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 8/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 10/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 12/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 14/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 16/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 18/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 20/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 22/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 24/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 26/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 28/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 30/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 32/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 34/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 36/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 38/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 40/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 42/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 44/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 46/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 48/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 50/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 52/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 54/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 56/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 58/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 60/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 62/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 64/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 66/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 68/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 70/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 72/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 74/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 76/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 78/82923 KB   
[20:02:11]:  [Step 4/4] 80/82923 KB
```

and this goes on and on.
How can I Supress this log?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use:

```
mvn --batch-mode ...
```